# Merging xml when xml is in use? (vb.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, merge

I have the following code which I would like to use to merge two xml files into one xml, But I keep messing it up along the way. Firstly I would like to open B.xml and merge it with A.xml. Once merged I would like to save it as C:\A.xml again, however I can't get it to overwrite itself because it's in use. At the moment I can only save A.xml merged with B.xml if the file name is other than C:\A.xml. is there a way around this?

```
        'create a openfile dialog
    Dim open_file As New OpenFileDialog

    'give its filter
    open_file.Filter = "Files (*.xml) | *.xml"
    open_file.Title = "Merge a Library"
    open_file.FileName = "Select a Library..."
    open_file.InitialDirectory = "C:\"

    Try

        'if ok click at opendialog
        If open_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim xmlreader1 As New XmlTextReader("C:\A.xml")

            Dim xmlreader2 As New XmlTextReader(open_file.FileName)

            Dim ds1 As New DataSet()
            Try
                ds1.ReadXml(xmlreader1)

                Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
                ds2.ReadXml(xmlreader2)

                ds1.Merge(ds2)
                ds1.WriteXml("C:\A.xml", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
                Console.WriteLine("Completed merging XML documents")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
            Console.Read()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

        'if any problem show error
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Dispose `XmlReader` before `ds1.WriteXml` call.

Answer (score 1):

The xmlTextReader object you are using are holding open handles to the xml files. In order to free up the resources you would need to call the `.Dispose()` method on both XML readers (first example below). However I would suggest placing your XMLTextReader objects inside of a `Using` block which will automatically call the `.Dispose()` method for you and make for cleaner code.

```vb
Try
    'if ok click at opendialog
    If open_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim xmlreader1 As New XmlTextReader("C:\A.xml")
        Dim xmlreader2 As New XmlTextReader(open_file.FileName)
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet()
        Try
            ds1.ReadXml(xmlreader1)

            Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
            ds2.ReadXml(xmlreader2)

            ds1.Merge(ds2)
            xmlreader1.Dispose()
            ds1.WriteXml("C:\A.xml", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
            Console.WriteLine("Completed merging XML documents")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If xmlreader1.ReadState <> ReadState.Closed Then xmlreader1.Dispose()
            xmlreader2.Dispose()
        End Try
        Console.Read()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    'if any problem show error
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

---

```vb
    Try
        'if ok click at opendialog
        If open_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim ds1 As New DataSet()
            Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
            Try
                Using xmlreader1 As New XmlTextReader("C:\A.xml")
                    ds1.ReadXml(xmlreader1)
                End Using

                Using xmlreader2 As New XmlTextReader(open_file.FileName)
                    ds2.ReadXml(xmlreader2)
                End Using

                ds1.Merge(ds2)

                ds1.WriteXml("C:\A.xml", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
                Console.WriteLine("Completed merging XML documents")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
            Console.Read()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'if any problem show error
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```